# Swagger versioning is not working. It displays all endpoints, despite the selected API version

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

all!

I am using Swagger in ASP.NET Core 3.1 application.

I need to create an endpoint for the new version of API and with the same route as a previous version.

My controller is:

```
namespace Application.Controllers
{
    [ApiVersion("1")]
    [ApiVersion("2")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}")]
    public class CustomController: ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("result")]
        public IActionResult GetResult()
        {
            return Ok("v1")
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [MapToApiVersion("2")]
        [Route("result")]
        public IActionResult GetResult(int number)
        {
            return Ok("v2")
        }
    }
}
```

My configuration:

```
            services.AddApiVersioning(
                options =>
                {
                    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
                });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc($"v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "api1", Version = $"v1" });

                c.SwaggerDoc($"v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "api2", Version = $"v2" });         
         

                c.OperationFilter<RemoveVersionParameterFilter>();
                c.DocumentFilter<ReplaceVersionWithExactValueInPathFilter>();
                c.EnableAnnotations();
            });
```

```
app.UseSwagger().UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v1/swagger.json", $"api1 v1");
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v2/swagger.json", $"api2 v2");
            });
```

After loading I get an error: **Fetch error undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json**
But If I change the second route to the "resutlTwo", I can observe both endpoints in swagger, ignoring current version (api1 v1 or api2 v2)

How can I see only 1 endpoint per API version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your case with this setup.You are missing `UrlSegmentApiVersionReader`.

```
public class SwaggerOptions
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string JsonRoute { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Version> Versions { get; set; }

    public class Version
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UiEndpoint { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In Startup#ConfigureServices

```
        // Configure versions 
        services.AddApiVersioning(apiVersioningOptions =>
        {
            apiVersioningOptions.ReportApiVersions = true;
            apiVersioningOptions.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
        });

        // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(swaggerGenOptions =>
        {
            var swaggerOptions = new SwaggerOptions();
            Configuration.GetSection("Swagger").Bind(swaggerOptions);

            foreach (var currentVersion in swaggerOptions.Versions)
            {
                swaggerGenOptions.SwaggerDoc(currentVersion.Name, new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = swaggerOptions.Title,
                    Version = currentVersion.Name,
                    Description = swaggerOptions.Description
                });
            }

            swaggerGenOptions.DocInclusionPredicate((version, desc) =>
            {
                if (!desc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                var versions = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetConstructors()
                    .SelectMany(constructorInfo => constructorInfo.DeclaringType.CustomAttributes
                        .Where(attributeData => attributeData.AttributeType == typeof(ApiVersionAttribute))
                        .SelectMany(attributeData => attributeData.ConstructorArguments
                            .Select(attributeTypedArgument => attributeTypedArgument.Value)));

                return versions.Any(v => $"{v}" == version);
            });

            swaggerGenOptions.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"));
            
            ... some filter settings here 
        });
```

In Startup#Configure

```
var swaggerOptions = new SwaggerOptions();
Configuration.GetSection("Swagger").Bind(swaggerOptions);
app.UseSwagger(option => option.RouteTemplate = swaggerOptions.JsonRoute);

app.UseSwaggerUI(option =>
{
  foreach (var currentVersion in swaggerOptions.Versions)
  {
    option.SwaggerEndpoint(currentVersion.UiEndpoint, $"{swaggerOptions.Title} {currentVersion.Name}");
  }
});
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Swagger": {
    "Title": "App title",
    "JsonRoute": "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json",
    "Description": "Some text",
    "Versions": [
      {
        "Name": "2.0",
          "UiEndpoint": "/swagger/2.0/swagger.json"
      },
      {
        "Name": "1.0",
        "UiEndpoint": "/swagger/1.0/swagger.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This code is very similar to a related issue I'm working on here on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks [Roar S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14072498/roar-s) for help!

I just added

```
 services.AddApiVersioning(apiVersioningOptions =>
            {
                apiVersioningOptions.ReportApiVersions = true;
                apiVersioningOptions.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
            });
```

and

```
 c.DocInclusionPredicate((version, desc) =>
                {
                    var endpointMetadata = desc.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata;

                    if (!desc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    var specificVersion = endpointMetadata
                            .Where(data => data is MapToApiVersionAttribute)
                            .SelectMany(data => (data as MapToApiVersionAttribute).Versions)
                            .Select(apiVersion => apiVersion.ToString())
                            .SingleOrDefault();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(specificVersion))
                    {
                        return $"v{specificVersion}" == version;
                    }

                    var versions = endpointMetadata
                            .Where(data => data is ApiVersionAttribute)
                            .SelectMany(data => (data as ApiVersionAttribute).Versions)
                            .Select(apiVersion => apiVersion.ToString());

                    return versions.Any(v => $"v{v}" == version);
                });
```

And it split endpoints to different files.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your working config. Yes, my config was kind of excessive, but I like to show how I tested your code. In many cases, there may be other parts that are missing.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys this code sample helped me a lot. You can use this for versions like 1.0 and 2.0. this worked for me

```
    c.DocInclusionPredicate((version, desc) =>
            {
                IList<object> endpointMetadata = desc.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata;

                if (!desc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                string specificVersion = endpointMetadata
                    .Where(data => data is MapToApiVersionAttribute)
                    .SelectMany(data => (data as MapToApiVersionAttribute).Versions)
                    .Select(apiVersion => apiVersion.ToString())
                    .SingleOrDefault();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(specificVersion))
                {
                    return $"v{specificVersion}" == version;
                }

                List<string> versions = endpointMetadata
                    .OfType<ApiVersionAttribute>()
                    .SelectMany(data => data.Versions)
                    .Select(apiVersion => apiVersion.ToString())
                    .Select(v =>
                    {
                        var versionParts = v.Split('.');
                        return versionParts.Length > 0 ? versionParts[0] : v;
                    })
                    .ToList();

                return versions.Any(v => $"v{v}" == version);
            });
```

thanks for the help <3

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?